# Xpath problem parsing child tags from parent tags that has style attribute

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Following is the snippet of html content:

```
<div class="post-inner wow bounceInUp animated" data-wow-offset='80' data-wow-delay="0s" data-wow-duration="0.8s">
   <a href="https://url.com/hello/" class="post-link"></a>
   <div class="post-pic lazyload" data-bg="https://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/opioid-300x200.jpg" *style="background-image: url('');" * /></div>
   <div class="tags-wrapper">
      <a href="/tag/hello-world">Hello World</a>
      <a href="/tag/noob">Noob</a>
   </div>
   <h3>
      <a href="https://url.com/hello/">
      My First Title-Hello</a>
   </h3>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the title and link inside h3.
What I am doing is:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> content = """
<div class="post-inner wow bounceInUp animated" data-wow-offset='80' data-wow-delay="0s" data-wow-duration="0.8s">
...    <a href="https://url.com/hello/" class="post-link"></a>
...    <div class="post-pic lazyload" data-bg="https://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/opioid-300x200.jpg" *style="background-image: url('');" * /></div
>
...    <div class="tags-wrapper">
...       <a href="/tag/hello-world">Hello World</a>
...       <a href="/tag/noob">Noob</a>
...    </div>
...    <h3>
...       <a href="https://url.com/hello/">
...       My First Title-Hello</a>
...    </h3>
... </div>"""
>>> html_response = fromstring(content)
>>> main_tag = html_response.xpath('//div[@class="post-inner wow bounceInUp animated"]')
>>> main_tag
[<Element div at 0x106b347e0>]
>>> main_tag[0].xpath('div')
[<Element div at 0x106b34788>]
>>> main_tag[0].xpath('a')
[<Element a at 0x106b34838>]
>>> main_tag[0].xpath('a/@href')
['https://url.com/hello/']
>>> main_tag[0].xpath('h3/a')
[]
>>> main_tag[0].xpath('h3')
[]
>>>
```

I am not able to go through **h3** tag here. And while troubleshooting, If I remove
`*style="background-image: url('');" * /`

I am able to extract  tag.

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Scrapy expert, but have you tried with a more direct XPATH?
Something like this '//div[@class="post-inner wow bounceInUp animated"]/h3/a'
With this, in Chrome's Console, I'm able to extract both title and href value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div` you are capturing closes at the end of the 3rd line (notice the first `div` at that line ends with `/>`). Hence, the `h3` element that you want to capture is not within that `div`.